# How can I change a tumblr og:image to be at least 200x200?

Tags: jquery, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to help my friend with his tumblr blog since I know code and he doesn't. Facebook Open Graph requires that an og:image be at least 200x200 to display the image when you link to your site, but tumblr forces an icon of 128x128 on your home page, so Facebook won't correctly link to your picture.

For example, visit Facebook's Object Debugger for [his site](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://lablfoto.com/) and you can see there is a warning saying

> Provided og:image is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200 px. Image 'http://24.media.tumblr.com/7058d8a59658ff7e39e8ee83a8a72fc9/tumblr_n2ho09BYPS1sej21so1_500.jpg' will be used instead.

I tried writing a jQuery function that should change the value of his `og:image` on his site, but it almost seems as if tumblr later goes in and changes the code after I have made my changes. Below is my code:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var metas = document.head.getElementsByTagName("meta");
    for (var i=0; i<metas.length;i++)
    {
        if(metas[i].getAttribute("property"))
            console.log(metas[i].getAttribute("property"));
        if(metas[i].getAttribute("property") == "og:image")
        {
            console.log("GOT IT!");
            metas[i].setAttribute("content", "http://25.media.tumblr.com/avatar_8c69b027eab0_512.png");
            console.log(metas[i].getAttribute("content"));
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

It seems to print out everything like how I would expect it to, but when I go to his site and view his source code, it keeps the old value for his og:image and not the new one that I set.

You can go to [his site](http://lablfoto.com/) and view the console to see that my code is printing out the expected results, but the og:image is not getting updated when you view the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not get executed when facebook reads the page for posting to its site. The jQuery gets ignored, so its going to grab the first large image on the page.

If you are just setting to the avatar. why not just hardcode the link in the tumblr theme HTML?

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://25.media.tumblr.com/avatar_8c69b027eab0_512.png"/>
```

Comment: I think that somehow the code is getting appended to the document head, because I don't see it in his Edit HTML section of tumblr. I have never tried developing on tumblr before, so I don't really know how it works. Here's a link of his HTML in his edit mode on tumblr (with no nod to og:image or any of the other facebook meta-tags:

http://startingtofeelit.com/tumblr.html

Comment: just paste the above code meta tag into the head of his tumblr page.

Comment: I did that. Facebook Graph Debugger still gets the old URL.

Comment: if you view the source
line 14 has one meta image tag
line 189 also has one so its getting reset.

Comment: I know, like I said something with tumblr is overriding it, so I'm not sure how I can stop it from overriding it.

Comment: Remove the other one, or see if there are options in the theme.